# MySQL HY000 1366: Trying to store 4 byte utf8 character

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I've battled with this issue in the past turned out the solution was to use `utf8mb4` charset because in mysql `utf8` does not support 4-byte long characters. My field:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  ...
  `body` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Then I try to insert this character "" and I get

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x82' for column 'body' at row 1

I'm using PHP PDO and I specify `charset=utf8mb4` in my DSN but I even tried inserting it directly by connecting to MySQL with a client and I still got the error. What am I missing?

Here is my PHP code setting up my connection

```
$charset = 'utf8mb4';
...
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset={$charset};", $user, $pass, [
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
]);
```

Added the settings in @sorak's answer, output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'`:

```
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

Comment: Seems to work. Could you please add your PHP code please? Fetch :   `array(2){["id"]=>string(1) "7",["body"]=>string(4) ""}`.

Comment: @Syscall I'm using a framework but as I mentioned in the question I'm setting the charset to `utf8mb4` in the DSN string and I'm using PDO prepared statements with question mark placeholders.

Comment: The entirety of the connection has to be on `utf8mb4`. Did you, for example, set it on the PHP connection? i.e. `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8mb4', "root", "root");`

Comment: @ishegg  yes that is exactly what I tried to explain. But I'm thinking it has nothing to do with PHP since when I try to insert this record using a mysql client manually I still get the error.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed it. So, I'll insist, *everything* has to be on `utf8mb4`. What's the database collation?

Comment: @ishegg everything is, database, table and column. They are all using `utf8mb4` charset with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation, tried `utf8mb4_general_ci` but doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: For information, my attempts in MySQL client failed but works in PHP using PDO.

Comment: The damns emojis are always a pain in the ass. Try running this query after connection: `SET NAMES utf8mb4`. Do you get the same error when you run it on the mysql client? Which client are you using?

Comment: @ishegg I added `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` with set names but the error still remains. I'm using navicat still unable to insert the damn emoji... Updated the question with my pdo construct.

Comment: What version of PHP?  Before or after 5.3.6?

Comment: @RickJames 7.0.8

Comment: You seem to have done everything correctly.  Please provide a _minimal self-contained_ PHP program and table definition that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer can be found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89355/unable-to-insert-utf8mb4-characters-in-mysql-5-6

Essentially, make sure that you have character set definitions specified in `my.cnf`:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

And then restart the service: `service mysql restart`

Comment: Hm. I was missing those settings entirely however I added them and restarted the daemon, still getting the error.

Comment: try: `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'`

Comment: Tried that without luck. Logic points that it's some kind of a server issue like the one you described.

Comment: when I run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'` I see that everything is `utf8mb4` as per the answer in the referenced question, however still not able to insert emoji.